# masking pasword in eclipse IDE java by bypassing the eclipse bug for console.readPassword()

Tags: java, eclipse, console, passwords, masking

im trying to mask password when i type my user input password it must be hidden or *. im using this readPassowrd method which has issues like null pointer error for performing the task in IDE but fine for Command line.
Is there anyways i can mask password in IDE only.

this is what i have below

```
char[] PASSWORD =console.readPassword("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD :");
log.info("Entered" + PASSWORD);
```

but i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` in console in the IDE.

Any help with this ?

Comment: Which Eclipse bug?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException when u run the program with readPassword()

Comment: That isn't an Eclipse bug.

Comment: ok @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that `java.io.Console` is NOT actually available always, but it depends by the implementation of your runtime environment.
Normally, it's hard to find an IDE which provides an instance of Console class, that's why you get `NullPointerException`, simply because when you launch your application with the IDE's "Run" command, the `System.console()` method returns `null`.
I am afraid this is not an issue of Eclipse, but it happens with IntelliJ and many other IDEs as well.

Personally, if I need to use the `Console`, what I normally do is to launch the application via the Terminal, because the JVM launched via `java` command it always returns a not-null instance of `java.io.Console`, so you can also test the `readPassword` method.
You can launch the terminal in Eclipse by right-clicking on output folder of your application and then select the menu "Show In -> Terminal", then you can launch the classic "java" command (hope you know how it works):

```
> java -cp . <YourMainClass>
```

Comment: is there a work around this i know it works from terminal

Comment: Unfortunately the Console doesn't exist at all with IDE as Eclipse, and there is no workaround for it, I don't even know whether exists a plugin which builds an instance of Console. As a matter of fact, you can see also that there are many threads opened on Eclipse foundation forum related to the topic and the answer is always the same. I am afraid you can only opt for the Terminal :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Console cnsl = null;
  
try {
   // creates a console object
   cnsl = System.console();

   // if console is not null
   if (cnsl != null) {
      // read password into the char array
      char[] pwd = cnsl.readPassword("Password: ");
      
      // prints
      System.out.println("Password is: "+pwd);
   } 
   
} catch(Exception ex) {
   // if any error occurs
   ex.printStackTrace();      
}
```

As it is described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/console_readpassword.htm)

Comment: this doesnt work nothing printed out in console, this is done in cmd not in IDE